# .net patterns : capture fields in a multi-line log file

Tags: .net, regex

I have a log file which looks like this :

2012-05-04 01:10:35;301383027;00133608663205759673480010256592;103;ERROR;AbstractTreatment:119;blah1

blah2

blah3

2012-05-02 01:00:22;301382163;00133591322220336011720010256592;103;ERROR;AbstractTreatment:119;blah4

blah5

blah6

2012-05-02 01:00:23;301382163;00133591322220336011720010256592;103;ERROR;AbstractTreatment:119;blah7

blah8

blah9

**I would like to have 3 matches with 3 captured groups in each: Date, Severity, and Message.**

I've tried to use this pattern

```
(20[0-9]{2}-[0-2][0-9]-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]);[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;([^;]*);(.*)
```

With Singleline option enabled, I have one match (the whole input), and with this option disabled, the message is not completely captured (only the part on the same line as the date is).

How could I have as many matches as log entries with the 3 values I want correctly captured?

EDIT:
I am trying to capture matches like this:

*Date:* 2012-05-04 01:10:35

*Severity:* ERROR

*Message:* AbstractTreatment:119;blah1

blah2

blah3

Comment: did you try to remove the ending .* ?

Comment: because the ending .* is the one crunching all the file till the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're 2 tricks here.

1. **"." does not include "\n"** and you don't need to set
   RegexOptions.Multiline.
2. You need to use another date/time pattern or end character($) as a
   delimiter, which should not be included in a match. (otherwise needs
   to exclude the delimiter from the input before searching for the
   next match).
   This needs to use a special grouping expression
   called "**Zero-Width Positive Lookahead Assertions**" with a syntax
   of (?= subexpression).

To test your log, I saved it in a "Log" setting variable.

```
string log = Settings.Default.Log;
string datePattern = @"20[0-9]{2}-[0-2][0-9]-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]";
string pattern = @"(?<date>" + datePattern + @");[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;(?<severity>[^;]*);(?<message>(.|\n)*?)(?=(" + datePattern + @"|$))";
Match mtc = Regex.Match(log, pattern);

while (mtc.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date: " + mtc.Groups["date"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Severity: " + mtc.Groups["severity"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + mtc.Groups["message"].Value);

    mtc = mtc.NextMatch();
}
```

Then the output is as follows,

```
Date: 2012-05-04 01:10:35
Severity: ERROR
Message: AbstractTreatment:119;blah1

blah2

blah3


Date: 2012-05-02 01:00:22
Severity: ERROR
Message: AbstractTreatment:119;blah4

blah5

blah6


Date: 2012-05-02 01:00:23
Severity: ERROR
Message: AbstractTreatment:119;blah7

blah8

blah9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Regex r = new Regex(
      @"^(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2});[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;(?<severity>[^;]*);(?<message>.*(\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};)[^\n]+)*)",
      RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

The idea is, after the `.*` consumes the remainder of the first line, `\n+` consumes one or more line separators and `[^\n]+` consumes the contents of the next non-empty line--but only if the lookahead - `(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};)` - fails to match a date at the beginning of the line.  (Because, of course, a line that starts with a date is presumed to be the start of the next log entry.)

The `Multiline` option causes the `^` anchor to match after a linefeed as well as at the beginning of the string.  `ExplicitCapture` means only named groups capture, so I don't have to use `(?:...)` to prevent plain groups from capturing.  It's a good idea to use `ExplicitCapture` whenever you use named groups; named and numbered groups interact oddly in .NET regexes.

Comment: It works, thanks!I had to choose between two good answers, sorry that  yours weren't picked.